# Mysql table is read only. privileges, owner are set

Tags: mysql, database

When I try to insert data into a db table, the read only error is showing up.
I already changed the owner of the mysql directory to mysql, as it's posted in similiar questions to this one.
The table was created with adminer webinterface, the database engine is MyISAM.
I tried to repair the table too, but that didnt fix the error.
Besides that, the user has all privileges.

May someone can help me, do I have to change something in the config file?

Edit:

After searching for two hours now I checked my storage engines again. I accidently used mrg_MyISAM instead of the normal MyISAM. Now everything's working fine.

Comment: Which one is "the read only error"?

Comment: 1036 error : table 'name' is read only

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix it by `GRANT` appropriate permissions for the user and host.  It isn't a file level thing; it's a SQL command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

I'd DROP the table, re-create it, and try again.

Comment: the sql user has all priviliges, i also tried it with the root sql user but its not working

Comment: is there some function that shows a list of all mysql users with their privileges?

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/2012/11/how-to-view-list-of-mysql-users-and-their-privileges.html #google

Comment: already found the db, all users are listed and have all privileges it must be a configuration problem.